# Trying to retrieve list of browser widths in New Relic but can't ORDER BY in NRQL

Tags: newrelic, nrql

I'm trying to get a list of all browser widths used and the number of times, in order of size.  So:

1920 - 12,356
1440 - 19,453
1280 - 10,847
1024 - 4,124

or something like that.  It's important to list them in order of width, not usage.  I'm using this:

`SELECT count(browserWidth) FROM PageAction FACET browserWidth ORDER BY browserWidth LIMIT 1000`

but the result I get back is ordered by most used browserWidth, not the browserWidth itself.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit arduous, but you can bucket them using `facet cases` eg:

```sql
SELECT count(*)  from PageAction facet cases
  (where browserWidth <= 1366 as '720p',
   where browserWidth > 1366 and browserWidth <= 1440 as '1440p',
   where browserWidth > 1440 and browserWidth <= 1680 as '1050p',
   where browserWidth > 1680 and browserWidth <= 1920 as '1080p',
   where browserWidth > 1920 and browserWidth <= 2560 as '1440p',
   where browserWidth > 2560 as '> 1440p')
since 30 days ago
```